# File download name converting to Id when it contains special/Unicode characters as file name

Tags: c#, file, unicode, docx

I am trying to download a file which contains special/Unicode characters as file name (ǟǾĂšĦ DeshďêŠħ (INQ0361).docx) and I want the file name remain as same but it is downloading with id like 1533.docx.

Please see my code below I am using

Controller:

```
 public FileResult Download(long id)
    {
        var document = UnitOfWork.Documents.GetById(id);
        return File(document.DocumentData, document.MimeType, document.Filename);
    }
```

View:

```
 <tbody>
            @foreach(var item in Model.OrderByDescending(c=>c.UpdatedDate))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(@item.FileName, "Download/" + item.DocumentId, new { Controller = "Document" }) </td>
                    <td>@item.FileSize.GetSizeString()</td>
                    <td>@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.UpdatedDate)</td>
                    <td>@item.UpdatedBy</td>
                    <td>@item.Note</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if any more information needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to this problem and please find below my fix

```
 public FileResult Download(long id)
  { var document = UnitOfWork.Documents.GetById(id);
    string filename = document.Filename; 
    filename = Uri.EscapeDataString(filename); 
    return File(document.DocumentData, document.MimeType, filename);
  }
```